# emeditor column selection seems dose not work good

Tags: selection

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxNFg.jpg)

I am expecting like this, and early version work as this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaCy7.jpg)

by the way, my version is Version 22.1.0

Answer (score 0):

got the answer. we should modify the font to mono.